# elixir get list elements by keyword

Tags: elixir

I'm working with `Map` and `List`.

In maps case, I only wish some elements, searching by keywords:

```
my_map = %{key1: "value1", key2: "value2", status: :success}
Map.take(my_map, [:key1, :status])

my_list_of_maps = [%{key1: "value1", key2: "value2", status: :success}, %{key1: "value3", key2: "value4", status: :error}, %{key1: "value5", key2: "value6", status: :success}]
```

Now, I wish to do the same thing with `my_list_of_maps`. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to take each map in `my_list_of_maps`, take only the `:key1` and `:status` keys out of it, and build a new list with the new maps. If this is correct, then you can map over `my_list_of_maps`:

```
Enum.map(my_list_of_maps, fn map -> Map.take(map, [:key1, :status])) end
```

I used [`Enum.map/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) in the example.

(small self-nitpick: idiomatic Elixir would probably write `&Map.take(&1, [:key1, :status])` instead of using `fn` here, but it's the same)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks @whatyouhide.